# Modifying the ssl version using openssl on wamp server

Tags: ssl, openssl, wamp, wampserver, beast

I am currently working on testing some vulnerabilities in TLS 1.0. I have created a website and hosted it on wamp server 2.4. I am using openssl to create self-signed certificates for SSL encryption ver. 1.01. But the current openssl version uses TLS 1.2 provide. I want to use TLS 1.0 rather to test some of the vulnerabilities such as BEAST attack present in TLS 1.0. I would like to know how can I modify the version so that the website now uses TLS 1.0 protocol instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try reading this [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html):

Then in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf` find this line

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
```

Then change that line to only include the protocol you want to test so it is the only one that is used.